# What options do we have to keeping our hard drive secure in case of theft?

Tags: security, encryption

If you have work files on your laptop that are sensitive, what measures can you take to keep things secure?

is it possible to encrypt the entire drive?

Answer (score 2):

OS X has supported full disk encryption since 10.7. See [Apple's KB article about FileVault 2](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4790).